# How to access external storage in Android 10?

Tags: android, android-external-storage, android-10.0

As per [Android 10 update](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#scoped-storage), Reading and writing from external storage is restricted even we have

> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

I want to move my pdf file from internal storage (private of my android app) to DOWNLOADS folder. I tried so many approaches but nothing worked and there is no any help available on internet related to accessing external storage in android 10.

Privacy changes in Android 10  |  Android Developers
https://developer.android.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope below code will help you to resolve your issue and copy any file from internal to external storage.

```
fun copyPdfFrom(context: Context, sourceFile: File, destinationURIString: String) {
                val destinationURI = Uri.parse(destinationURIString)
                try {
                    val bufferedInputStream = BufferedInputStream(FileInputStream(sourceFile.absoluteFile))
                    val outPutStream = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(destinationURI)!!
                    var len = 0
                    val brr = ByteArray(1024)

                    while ((bufferedInputStream.read(brr, 0, brr.size).also { len = it }) != -1) {
                        outPutStream.write(brr, 0, len)
                    }
                    outPutStream.flush()
                    outPutStream.close()
                    bufferedInputStream.close()
                }
                catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
```